# Exchange online, New-DynamicDistributionGroup with phone number

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

I'm trying to create a DDG with powershell that returns all users that have mobile phone.

I've checked which propireties are filtrable and I've created the group with:

```
New-DynamicDistributionGroup -Name "Groupname" -RecipientFilter "(RecipientType -eq 'UserMailbox') -and (Phone -ne '$null')"
```

And the group gets created successfully, but when I try to see the user in group with the command below I get this error:

```
$FTE = Get-DynamicDistributionGroup "GroupName"
Get-Recipient -RecipientPreviewFilter $FTE.RecipientFilter -OrganizationalUnit $FTE.RecipientContainer
```

```
The recipient preview filter string "((Phone -ne '') -and (-not(Name -like 'SystemMailbox{*')) -and (-not(Name -like 'CAS_{*')) -and (-not(RecipientTypeDetailsValue
-eq 'MailboxPlan')) -and (-not(RecipientTypeDetailsValue -eq 'DiscoveryMailbox')) -and (-not(RecipientTypeDetailsValue -eq 'PublicFolderMailbox')) -and
(-not(RecipientTypeDetailsValue -eq 'ArbitrationMailbox')) -and (-not(RecipientTypeDetailsValue -eq 'AuditLogMailbox')) -and (-not(RecipientTypeDetailsValue -eq
'AuxAuditLogMailbox')) -and (-not(RecipientTypeDetailsValue -eq 'SupervisoryReviewPolicyMailbox')))" is neither a valid OPath filter nor a valid LDAP filter. Use the
-RecipientPreviewFilter parameter with either a valid OPath filter string or a valid LDAP filter string.
```

all the other filter string are created automatically buy exchange I guess, what could be the issue?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: "when I try to see the user in group" - using which command?

Comment: Don't post code in comments, [edit it into your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/63520823/edit) instead

Comment: Noted, I've made the change